# FFmpeg: complex command for extracting image

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

**My ffmpeg for my ANDROID APPLICATION on android studio 2.3.3 is compiled using this:**

> compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

**In the code below i have this line of code:**

> String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-c:v", "libx264",
>   "-crf", "22", "-map", "0", "-segment_time", "6", "-g", "9",
>   "-sc_threshold", "0", "-force_key_frames", "expr:gte(t,n_forced*6)",
>   "-f", "segment", dest.getAbsolutePath()};

**What i want to know:**

1. How do i change that complex command that i have such that i can get the last 15 frames of a 2 seconds-long 30fps video.

**This is the code I'm referencing:**

```
     /**
     * Command for extracting images from video
     */
    private void extractImagesVideo(int startMs, int endMs) {
        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        );

        String filePrefix = "extract_picture";
        String fileExtn = ".jpg";
        String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);

        File dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor");
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dir.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor" + fileNo);

        }
        dir.mkdir();
        filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);


        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());

        String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-r", "1/2", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};

        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);

    }

 /**
     * Executing ffmpeg binary
     */
    private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
                    if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 5 || choice == 6 || choice == 7) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 3) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewImageActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 4) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioPreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 8) {
                        choice = 9;
                        reverseVideoCommand();
                    } else if (Arrays.equals(command, lastReverseCommand)) {
                        choice = 10;
                        concatVideoCommand();
                    } else if (choice == 10) {
                        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
                        );
                        File destDir = new File(moviesDir, ".VideoPartsReverse");
                        File dir = new File(moviesDir, ".VideoSplit");
                        if (dir.exists())
                            deleteDir(dir);
                        if (destDir.exists())
                            deleteDir(destDir);
                        choice = 11;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
```

**Code downloaded from:**

https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`select`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) filter to select specific frames by their index.

2 seconds of video at 30 fps have 60 frames, so you want all frames from 45 onwards:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "select='gte(n,45)'" -vsync 0 out-%04d.png
```

There are other selection expressions like `lte` or `between`, see [Expression Evaluation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Expression-Evaluation) in the ffmpeg docs. `-vsync 0` drops frame timestamps to eliminate duplicates.

The final command would look like this:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-framerate", "60", "-vf", "select='gte(n,45)'", "-vsync", "0", dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

Comment: Hey @slhck how do i go about implementing ur code into mine? Simply changing the ComplexCommand like so: String[] complexCommand = {ffmpeg, "-i" ,"input.mp4", "-vf", "select=gte(n\,45)", "out-%04d.png"}; doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? You may not have to use a backslash when calling it via Java, so try just `select=gte(n,45)`. If it does not work, please show some error output.

Comment: I get these errors:
I cant use '\'  it gives an error "illegal escape character" during build.

With the slash: [AVFilterGraph @ 0xf689a080] Error initializing filter 'select' with args 'gte(n/'
Without the slash: [AVFilterGraph @ 0xf689a080] Error initializing filter 'select' with args 'gte(n'

Comment: String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-r", "60", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};

The above complexCommand allowed me to grab all 60 frames from a 60fps 1 second video, but what i need is the last "x" amount of frames Idk how to change the complex command to fit my needs

Comment: I can't try it on my system, but perhaps you can try: `"select='gte(n,45)'"` (with single quotes).

Comment: Hey it worked, but I'd like to know what the 45 means, in a 1 second video at 60fps, i have an output of 99 images ._. which is weird.

Comment: It selects each frame from frame number 45 onwards, see here: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Examples-144 — can you send me a sample video?

Comment: Here's the code & video: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Kt9KpV9HnRaC1Id1g4NTZxazQ

Comment: Thank you very much for your help i managed to get it to work, here's the final complexcommand, -vsync 0 alllowed me to remove the extra duplicate frames(they were duplicates of frame 45)

String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-framerate", "60", "-vf", "select='gte(n,45)'", "-vsync", "0",  dest.getAbsolutePath()};